# Git push sub-folders of a commit separately

Tags: git, git-push

I have a local git repository which contains a root folder and some sub-folders. I know that I can push my project to Github using below commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initialization"
git remote add origin "my github repo"
git push origin master
```

but because the volume of my repository is about 30 GB (it is a data set), my laptop hangs when compressing data, so I need to push each sub-folder separately to reduce the data I push. How can I push the sub-folders of a commit separately?

Comment: What is *git remove add origin "my github repo"* supposed to do. Can you just do a separate commits per directory?

Comment: Why is your repo 30 GB? Git is not designed to efficiently store that much data.

Comment: Look into lfs for git

Answer (score 2):

Since the process hangs, you can reset everything, by removing the `.git/` folder created by `git init`.

Then you can create your repo again, add your remote origin, and this time:

```
git add folder1
git commit -m "Add folder1"
git push -u origin master
```

Then repeat for `folder2`:

```
git add folder2
git commit -m "Add folder2"
git push
```

But do consider first if you can add to your `.gitignore` files/binaries that can be regenerated from sources, or anything which would reduce the size of the Git repo.

Depending on your remote repo hosting service (like github.com for instance), you can have limitation to the size of a commit or of a full repo.
GitHub (again, for instance) documents that in "[What is my disk quota?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/)".

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Great Help

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Great answer indeed!